# Create a menu item to sent to pen drive?

Tags: 11.10, menu, clipboard

Im very new to Ubuntu Linux environment and loving it. Can some one suggest me how to insert a plugged in USB storage to Copy to menu in Ubuntu 11.10. how one can copy to move to a removable drive am not sure how that can be incorporated.

**Windows example**

http://kb.sandisk.com/euf/assets/images/faqs/104/id104-st-win7-4.gif

**Ubuntu Copy to Menu**

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Bfsp-nUDnTo/ToGj_qoIk4I/AAAAAAAAAHE/DlpChUacu1s/s1600/Install-playerstage-extracting-tar.gz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite certain you can't copy to a pen drive like how it is in Windows but you can simply use 'copy' and 'paste' function from a 'right click' to copy things onto the pen drive. Hope this helps

Comment: yeah i getting to hang of it now! the pen drive must be mounted first. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help :)